# SICP exercise 5.20

Tags: memory, cpu-registers, sicp

The exercise is from [§5.3.1](https://mitp-content-server.mit.edu/books/content/sectbyfn/books_pres_0/6515/sicp.zip/full-text/book/book-Z-H-33.html#%25_sec_5.3.1), and the text is copied below:

> Draw the box-and-pointer representation and the memory-vector representation (as in figure [5.14](https://mitp-content-server.mit.edu/books/content/sectbyfn/books_pres_0/6515/sicp.zip/full-text/book/book-Z-H-33.html#%25_fig_5.14)) of the list structure produced by
>
> ```scm
> (define x (cons 1 2))
> (define y (list x x))
> ```
>
> with the `free` pointer initially `p1`. What is the final value of `free`? What pointers represent the values of `x` and `y`?

I think what confuses me is precisely [the linked figure](https://mitp-content-server.mit.edu/books/content/sectbyfn/books_pres_0/6515/sicp.zip/full-text/book/book-Z-H-33.html#%25_fig_5.14),

[image]

considering that it's not explicitly mentioned ***why*** the entries 1, 2, 4, 5, and 7 are used.

I assume that the reason is that those where the first 5 free slots when the example list structure `((1 2) 3 4)` was allocated. After all, that list must come from a `'((1 2) 3 4)` in Scheme code, which is the same as `(cons (cons 1 (cons 2 '()) (cons 3 (cons 4 '()))))`, and about `cons` I read

> `Cons` is performed by allocating an unused index and storing the arguments to `cons` in `the-cars` and `the-cdrs` at that indexed vector position.

If that's the case, then I believe the solution to the exercise is as follows, assuming the memory is all free initially:

```
       ┌───┬───┐    ┌───┬───┐
  y ──>│ + │ ──┼───>│ + │ / │
       └─┼─┴───┘    └─┼─┴───┘
         │            │
         ├────────────┘
         │
         v
       ┌───┬───┐    ┌───┐
  x ──>│ + │ +─┼───>│ 2 │
       └─┼─┴───┘    └───┘
         │
         │
         v
       ┌───┐
       │ 1 │
       └───┘

              0    1    2    3    4    5
            ┌────┬────┬────┬────┬────┬────┬────┬────┬────
  the-cars  │    │ n1 │ p1 │ p1 │    │    │    │    │
            ├────┼────┼────┼────┼────┼────┼────┼────┼────
  the-cdrs  │    │ n2 │ e0 │ p2 │    │    │    │    │
            └────┴────┴────┴────┴────┴────┴────┴────┴────
                   ^         ^    ^
                   |         |    |
                   |         |    |
                   x         y   free
```

Otherwise, I think, I should have been given an "evolution" for `free`, no?

Comment: The indices 1, 2, 4, 5, and 7 are arbitrary. The book assumes that at the time the list was created, those slots happened to be available.

Comment: So my solution to the exercise is correct, assuming that the slots 1, 2, and 3 were the available when `x` and `y` are created.